# CITRIX and disabled "Copy/Paste"

Tags: copy-paste, citrix

I must use several **Citrix** desktops, where "**COPY/PASTE**" from the local machine to the server is **disabled**. Are there workarounds or tricks to bypass this limitation?

Comment: Citrix is a plague. I never had a so bad experience with remote access than any other competitors product. I share your pain.

Comment: adding a comment to say that I just updated citrix  on my home machine (October 27, 2020) and I currently can't copy and paste in any programs at all, not just citrix-based programs. If you're reading this in 2020 and investigating a similar problem on your machine, let me know.

Comment: It's 2022 and I still have the plague

Answer (score 9):

I've encountered the same problem and have a partial somewhat contrived solution. It allows me to get a little more than 1kb of text from sandboxed Internet Explorer instance.

I use http://goqr.me/ to create a QR-code from the text. Create it in greatest possible resolution and open it. Take a screenshot of the window on the clipboard by pressing Alt-PrtScr. Then I use a small utility (see https://github.com/thoraage/qrscanner) to extract text from the picture on the clipboard.

It is a sick world!

Answer (score 7):

The earlier suggestions and *"work-arounds"* were useful, but in 2020, there is a better way :)

Microsoft developed a "Relay Service" called [Azure Relay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-what-is-it). This same service is what's used behind the scenes to power what Microsoft refers to as "Live Code Sharing".

This service runs as an extension with several products, but for developers, this would likely be their IDE and code editor: Visual Studio and VS Code.

The extension is [Live Share](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/live-share/) and it works flawlessly (at least on my machine )

Like other suggestions, this isn't going to let you copy/paste from one machine to another, but in a way, it allows for much more. Instead, this alternative will let you host a project/workspace/notes...etc on your local machine, start a live-share session, then join that live share session from the remote.

Whether you work from the local or the remote, the changes persist and are shared on each machine.

Thanks the other commenters for their suggestions. I may not have thought of this as an option without the prior suggestions to spark this idea.

Comment: You can even use the browser version of VS Code if you have issues with firewall. Great answer @Prancer!

Comment: I was insprired by this answer and found a good solution for me: You can also use MS OneNote, which can be used in Browser or as native app in most environments. There you can also copy&paste images or tables :)

Answer (score 6):

Best solution for this, I used just open one note app in local machine.

1. Open citrix and Restore (resize the window []).
2. Snip the entire text as image and paste it in one note.
3. Right click on the image and copy the text.
4. Paste it in TXT doc you got that.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it's just gibberish.

Answer (score 5):

I just open two gmails and sent the info through chat.

Example:

- Local computer open GMAIL 1
- Remote Citrix Computer open GMAIL 2
- Copy from local computer and paste into google hangout with Gmail 2
- Send
- Done! it will be ready to be copy on Gmail 2 in remote citrix computer!

Cheers

Comment: Ha h ah ah ah ah. Great solution :-)

Answer (score 2):

I was running on a similar situation but in my case I was trying to copy files from remote (Windows) to local.

To solve that issue I killed the rdpclip.exe on remote and started it again.

Comment: This solution worked for me in 2020 and did not require a workaround like the other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to defined it in the Citrix policy to only restricted or not restrict based on certain conditions.

The answer would also depend on the direction you are coming from? As a user trying to circumvent the system, or a tech trying to have a select group of users approved to do so.

I'm not aware of any tricks, to circumvent.

jezr

Answer (score 0):

If it is just about a picture/ screenshot I suggest the following workaround:
1. open the picture/ file in citrix
2. change to your local machine, open Snipping Tool (Windows)
3. make a screenshot of the citrix content

Answer (score -1):

Solution for this problem:

1. Open IE explorer and open internet options and open security tab then open trusted sites add your Citrix website which you want to access.
2. Restore advanced settings in in advanced tab.
3. Clear your temporary files.
4. Download Citrix receiver then check for copy paste